# how do i clear a textfield in backbone.js after i click the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

my input is in HTML file my button is here in js file. Im a beginner here please teach me. Im still confuse of backbone.js

```
 var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    events: {
        'click button#add': 'addItem'

    },
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem', 'appendItem');

        this.collection = new List();
        this.collection.bind('add', this.appendItem);

        this.counter = 0;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.el).append("<button id='add' class='btn btn-primary clear'>Add Items</button>");
        $(this.el).append("<ul class='ul_adjust'></ul>");
        _(this.collection.model).each(function (item) {
            appendItem(item);
        }, this);
    },

    addItem: function () {

        var item = new Item();
        item.set({
            part1: $("#name").val()
        });

        this.collection.add(item);
    },
    appendItem: function (item) {
        var itemView = new ItemView({
            model: item
        });

        $('ul', this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
    },


});
```

did you get it?
i remove some of not necessary but i think this will be inserted somewhere here.

Comment: You should use `this.$el` instead of `$(this.el)`. Also, to find elements within the view, use `this.$(selector)`. Backbone collections already have a `each` function, you can call it directly `this.collection.each(function(){ ... }, this);`. Use `this.listenTo` instead of `bind` or `bindAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `events` is setup so that when you click the `#add` button, it calls the `addItem` function. So you just need to clear the textbox `#name` in this same function.

I would simply do:

```
$("#name").val("");
```

at the end of your `addItem` function, after `this.collection.add(item);` so the value is only cleared when you no longer need it.

Comment: can you give me which line should i insert? do i need an events?

Comment: Your `events` is setup so that when you click the `#add` button, it calls the `addItem` function. So you just need to clear the textbox `#name` in this same function. Do it last (add it after `this.collection.add(item);`) so the value is only cleared at the end and is still available while you need it.

Comment: Please edit additional details into your answer. Also, I would use `this.$('#name').val('')` instead.

Comment: Thanks, Emile, I've updated the answer. I was not aware that `this.$()` was an alias for `this.$el.find()`! That's really useful, though I'm not sure it's necessary when targeting an ID as it should be unique in the DOM. Is it actually faster or better practice to still narrow down ID selectors?